# TMP vs PDF in BLOB

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

I have an html form which is inserting file to mysql database as a blob. For images its working quite oky but there is a challenge for PDFs. below is the function that am using

```
public function insertBlob($filePath, $mime) {
        $blob = fopen($filePath, 'rb');

        $sql = "INSERT INTO files(mime,data) VALUES(:mime,:data)";
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':mime', $mime);
        $stmt->bindParam(':data', $blob, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

        return $stmt->execute();
    }
```

now when I use the function above by providing local full path like 
`$blobObj->insertBlob("C:\Users\User\Downloads\WEST.pdf","application/pdf");`, 
the pdf file is able to be pulled back and be viewed in chrome. But when I provide the path of tmp which I get from $FILES['myfile'][tmp_name], the file like

```
if(isset($_POST["save"])){
    $blob= $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["attachment"]["type"];
    var_dump($_FILES);
    // test insert object
    $blobObj->insertBlob($blob, $type);

}
```

uploaded pdf is not being able to be pulled and render in chrome, chrome says **file not supported**. What am I missing here? your help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in Blob, you need to encode your data using base64_encode().

Use this to display your content

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(data) ?>" type="application/pdf" 
  style="height:200px;width:60%"></object>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I was looking for something like this, I hope I will be able to use the same to download the file, much appreciations